# How to allow app to send push notification UWP?

Tags: notifications, uwp, windows-10-universal

My app shows notification to notify the user of some status. But these notifications doesn't show up when "Get notifications from apps and other senders" is turned off in the settings.

Is there a way for my UWP app to ask the user to allow the app to send push notification or to turn on push notification? Or maybe redirect the user to the settings where they can turn it on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But these notifications doesn't show up when "Get notifications from apps and other senders" is turned off in the settings

If notifications are prevented by this setting that is disabled by user, you should be able get this disabled reason from `Setting` property of [`ToastNotifier`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier) class. The reason should be `DisabledForUser`. And then you can redirect the user to the Notifications setting page as you thought by [`Launcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcher) to promote the user to change the settings.

For example:

```
private async void btnlaunch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ 
    var notifier = Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
    if (notifier.Setting != Windows.UI.Notifications.NotificationSetting.Enabled)
    {
        await Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("ms-settings:notifications"));
    }
}
```

More details please reference [Launch the Windows Settings app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).